# MySql graph query multiple series aligned to same time x-axis

Tags: mysql

I have queries that I'm using to make a graph of earnings. But now people are able to earn from two different sources, so I want to separate this out into two lines on the same chart

This one for standard earnings:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(earning_created, '%c/%e/%Y') AS day, SUM(earning_amount) AS earning_standard
FROM earnings
WHERE earning_account_id = ? AND earning_referral_id = 0 AND (earning_created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 DAY))
GROUP BY DATE(earning_created)
ORDER BY earning_created
```

And this one for referral earnings:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(e.earning_created, '%c/%e/%Y') AS day, SUM(e.earning_amount) AS earning_referral
FROM earnings AS e
INNER JOIN referrals AS r
ON r.referral_id = e.earning_referral_id
WHERE e.earning_account_id = ? AND e.earning_referral_id > 0 AND (e.earning_created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)) AND r.referral_type = 0
GROUP BY DATE(e.earning_created)
ORDER BY e.earning_created
```

How do I get it to run the queries together, so that it outputs two columns/series for the y-axis: `earning_standard` and `earning_referral`.

But with them both aligned to the same `day` column/scale for the x-axis - substituting zero when there are no earnings for a specific series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to set both of those queries as subqueries

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(earnings.earning_created, '%c/%e/%Y') AS day, 
       COALESCE(es.earning_standard, 0) AS earning_standard, 
       COALESCE(er.earning_referral, 0) AS earning_referral
FROM earnings
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(earning_created, '%c/%e/%Y') AS day,   
                  SUM(earning_amount) AS earning_standard
           FROM earnings
           WHERE earning_account_id = ? 
           AND earning_referral_id = 0 
           AND (earning_created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 DAY))
           GROUP BY DATE(earning_created)) AS es 
ON (day = es.day)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(e.earning_created, '%c/%e/%Y') AS day,    
                  SUM(e.earning_amount) AS earning_referral
           FROM earnings AS e
           INNER JOIN referrals AS r
           ON r.referral_id = e.earning_referral_id
           WHERE e.earning_account_id = ? 
           AND e.earning_referral_id > 0 
           AND (e.earning_created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)) 
           AND r.referral_type = 0
           GROUP BY DATE(e.earning_created)) AS er 
ON (day = er.day)
WHERE earnings.earning_account_id = ?
ORDER BY day
```

where I'm assuming `earning_account_id = ?` is intended to be with a question mark because the language you're using to run the query is replacing it with the actual id before running the query.

Comment: yes, I'm using mysqli for prepared statements. It's 1AM here right now but I'll give it a test tomorrow! THANKS so much for your help! I don't know if it matters to you or not, but I'll send 50 bounty when it allows me, if it works! :))

Comment: Unfortunately it gives the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS es 
ON earnings.day = es.day
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(e.earning_created,' at line 11

Comment: Sorry, missing a close paren there. Added it in.

Comment: Now it gives this: #1054 - Unknown column 'earnings.day' in 'on clause'

Comment: I think I might have adapted your answer though - can you take a look at it and tell me if you think it will work?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 

COALESCE(t1.amount,0) AS link_earnings, 
COALESCE(t2.amount,0) AS publisher_referral_earnings, 
COALESCE(t3.amount,0) AS advertiser_referral_earnings, 
t1.day AS day

FROM

(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(earning_created, '%c/%e/%Y') AS day, SUM(earning_amount) AS amount
    FROM earnings
    WHERE earning_referral_id = 0 
    AND (earning_created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 DAY))
    AND earning_account_id = ?
    GROUP BY DATE(earning_created)
) t1

LEFT JOIN

(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ep.earning_created, '%c/%e/%Y') AS day, (SUM(ep.earning_amount) * rp.referral_share) AS amount
    FROM earnings AS ep
    INNER JOIN referrals AS rp
    ON ep.earning_referral_id = rp.referral_id
    WHERE ep.earning_referral_id > 0 
    AND (ep.earning_created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 DAY))
    AND ep.earning_account_id = ?
    AND rp.referral_type = 0
    GROUP BY DATE(ep.earning_created)
) t2

ON t1.day = t2.day

LEFT JOIN

(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ea.earning_created, '%c/%e/%Y') AS day, (SUM(ea.earning_amount) * ra.referral_share) AS amount
    FROM earnings AS ea
    INNER JOIN referrals AS ra
    ON ea.earning_referral_id = ra.referral_id
    WHERE ea.earning_referral_id > 0 
    AND (ea.earning_created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 DAY))
    AND ea.earning_account_id = ?
    AND ra.referral_type = 1
    GROUP BY DATE(ea.earning_created)
) t3

ON t1.day = t3.day

ORDER BY day
```

Seems to run ok....

Comment: So, the subqueries are pretty different than your question but assuming they encompass what you want it looks like you're golden.

Comment: Yes, I sort of simplified the question. I learned A LOT from this!! Yes, I hope so - you definitely led me in the right direction - i'll send 50 when it lets me - thanks again!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use an *outer* join to retain earnings even when there is no matching referral, and then conditionally sum depending on whether a referral exists or not:

```
SELECT   DATE_FORMAT(e.earning_created, '%c/%e/%Y') AS day,
         SUM(IF(r.referral_id IS NULL, e.earning_amount, 0)) earning_standard,
         SUM(IF(r.referral_id IS NULL, 0, e.earning_amount)) earning_referral
FROM     earnings e LEFT JOIN referrals r ON r.referral_id = e.earning_referral_id
WHERE    e.earning_account_id = ?
     AND e.earning_created > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 90 DAY
     AND (r.referral_id IS NULL OR r.referral_type = 0)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

I've assumed here that `earnings.earning_referral_id` is never negative, though you can add an explicit test to filter such records if so desired.

I've also changed the filter on `earnings.earning_created` to base from `CURRENT_DATE` rather than `NOW()` to ensure that any earnings created earlier than the current time on the first day of the series are still included—this would typically be what one actually wants, but feel free to change back if not.

Comment: Interesting, I'll see if this runs more efficiently tomorrow :)